# VHDL password program with DE2-board

Tags: passwords, vhdl

**Summary:**

I'm trying to make a password system in VHDL with the DE2 Altera board. SW 0 to 7 is the combination lock, LEDR 0 to 7 shows the current code and signal 'code' stores the combination. When the switches match the code you have the option to change the code by holding down KEY(1).

**Problem:**

The code works as it should, only the starter code is not what's expected. It should be: "01010101" as shown in the signal; but it comes out as "01111111". I suspect the program enters the if-statement on startup, but I don't see how that's possible, seeing as 'code' and SW should't be equal.
What am I missing?

### Here is the code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity pass_sys is
    port(
        SW : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        KEY : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        LEDR : out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
        LEDG : out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0)
    );
end pass_sys;

architecture func of pass_sys is
signal code : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "01010101"; --start code
begin

process(SW)
begin
    LEDR(7 downto 0)<=code;

    if (SW = code) then
        LEDG(0)<='1';
        LEDG(1)<=not KEY(1);
        if (KEY(1) = '0') then
            code<=SW;
        end if;
    else
        LEDG(0)<='0';
    end if;
end process;

end func;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem happens on your board, not in simulation. If I'm wrong, my answer is not the one you expect.

This initialization way is usefull only in simulation :

```
signal code : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := "01010101"; --start code
```

Synthesis will not consider your initialization value (That's why I discourage you to use this, except in test bench). If you want to initialize a signal, I advice to use a reset.

Notes :

- You should put *KEY* in sensitivity list and put this line out of your process :

```
LEDR(7 downto 0)<=code;
```

- Your process infers latches, it's not forbidden but you must be careful with this

**EDIT : How to add a reset**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity pass_sys is
    port(
        RST : in std_logic;
        SW : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        KEY : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        LEDR : out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
        LEDG : out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0)
    );
end pass_sys;

architecture func of pass_sys is
signal code : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin

LEDR(7 downto 0)<=code;

process(SW, code, KEY)
begin

    if RST = '1' then
        LEDG <= (others => '0');
        code <= "01010101";
    elsif (SW = code) then
        LEDG(0)<='1';
        LEDG(1)<=not KEY(1);
        if (KEY(1) = '0') then
            code<=SW;
        end if;
    else
        LEDG(0)<='0';
    end if;
end process;

end func;
```

The pin *RST* of your component could be connected to an analogic signal of you card (POWER_GOOD, ALIM_ON, DONE, ...) or to a pll_locked signal of a PLL if you use it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit of a beginner - how do I change my code to use a reset?

Comment: @mvraa I've added the answer to my post.